# How to find string length in php with out using strlen()?

Tags: php, string

How can you find the length of a string in php with out using `strlen()` ?

Comment: Out of interest - why don't you want to use strlen? Encoding issues?

Comment: Its like "I want to eat cake but don't want to use Knife to cut it, is there any other way.....!!!!!" :)

Comment: The time taken by `strlen` function is proportional to the length of string. So yes, I like to see an alternate solution.

Comment: @Salman A: all current answers either use `strlen` internally or implement it, and are therefore also O(n). The only O(1) answer is to store it somewhere beforehand.

Comment: From the comments you've made it looks like you're obsessing over a [tag:micro-optimization].  First off, this is almost certainly a waste of time because unless you're processing an utterly huge string or processing strings in a very tight loop the speed of strlen is a non-issue.  If your script is slow then I suggest profiling it to find where the real problem is.  Second, no solution you can come up by yourself will be faster than PHP strlen

Comment: https://www.w3schools.in/php/strlen-function-2#:~:text=Counting%20the%20Length%20of%20a%20String%20Using%20Loops&text=php%20%24String%20%3D%20'w3schools.,%22.%22%3B%20%3F%3E

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a pretty old issue, but this piece of code worked for me.

```
$s = 'string';
$i=0;
while ($s[$i] != '') {
  $i++;
}
print $i;
```

Comment: Bad code, will error out.

Answer (score 7):

```
 $inputstring="abcd";
 $tmp = '';    $i = 0;

   while (isset($inputstring[$i])){
        $tmp .= $inputstring[$i];
        $i++;
    }

echo $i; //final string count
echo $tmp; // Read string
```

while - Iterate the string character `1` by `1`

`$i` - gives the final count of string.

`isset($inputstring[$i])` - check character exist(null) or not.

Comment: While this answers the question, it would be much better with some explanation.

Comment: Will report a length of 1 for empty strings

Comment: @GordonM I have update the answer. Now for empty string it will return 0.

Answer (score 4):

I guess there's the `mb_strlen()` function.

It's not `strlen()`, but it does the same job (with the added bonus of working with extended character sets).

If you really want to keep away from anything even related to `strlen()`, I guess you could do something like this:

```
$length = count(str_split($string));
```

I'm sure there's plenty of other ways to do it too. The real question is.... uh, why?

Answer (score 3):

Lets be silly

```
function stupidCheck($string)
{
    $count = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<66000; $i++)
    {
       if(@$string[$i] != "")$count++;
       else break;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: `function string_count($string)
{
    $cnt=1;
    $count = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
    {
       if(@$string[$i] != ""){
        $count++;
       $cnt+=1;}
       else break;
    }
    return $count;
}
`

Comment: @WesleyvanOpdorp  I've modified function to make it more readable. There is no need of if else inside for loop. There is also no need to loop it 66000 times unnecessarily.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a joke given the use of @ which is known to be horribly slow.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can use the below code.

```
<?php
     $string="Vasim";
     $i=0;
     while(isset($string[$i]))
     {
        $i++;
     }
     echo $i;  // Here $i has length of string and the answer will be for this string is 5.
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Vaibhav Jain will throw the following notice on the last index.

*Notice: Uninitialized string offset*

I would like to give an alternative for this:

```
<?php

$str = 'India';

$i = 0;
while(@$str[$i]) {
    $i++;
}

echo 'Length of ' . $str . ' is ' . $i . '.';
```

Comment: Can you explain, Why without using @ it is producing "Notice: Uninitialized string offset" and how @ is handling this problem ?

Comment: '@' is an error control operator used in PHP. When we prepend this to any expression, errors that might occur for that expression will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In newer PHP versions, you can use [`null coalescing operator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to achieve this.

```
<?php

$string = 'test';

for($i = 0; ($string[ $i] ?? false) !== false; ++$i);

echo $i;// outputs length of the string.
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhx9kj83)

Answer (score 1):

`mb_strlen` — Get string length

```
 $string ='test strlen check';
 print 'mb_strlen(): ' . mb_strlen( $string, 'utf8' ) . "\n\n";
```

synatx: `int mb_strlen ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`

*str* - The string being checked for length.

*encoding* - The encoding parameter is the character encoding. If it is omitted, the internal character encoding value will be used.

Comment: your synatx is off :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also cheat with something like:

```
print strtok(substr(serialize($string), 2), ":");
```

Or this one is quite amusing:

```
print array_sum(count_chars($string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mystrlen($str)
{
    $i = 0;
    while ($str != '')
    {
        $str = substr($str, 1);
        $i++;
    }
    return $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findStringLength($string) {
    $length = 0;
    $lastStringChar1 = '1';
    $lastStringChar2 = '2';

    $string1 = $string . $lastStringChar1;
    $string2 = $string . $lastStringChar2;

    while ($string1[$length] != $lastStringChar1 || $string2[$length] != $lastStringChar2) {
        $length++;
    }

    return $length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for finding string length without using strlen() function.

```
<?php
function stringlength($withoutstringlength)
{
    $n = 0;
    while(substr($withoutstringlength, $n, $n+1) != '')//General syntax substr(string,start,length)
    {
        $n++;
    }
    echo $n;
}
stringlength("i am a php dev");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function length($value){

    if(empty($value[1])) return 1;

    $n = 0;
    while(!empty($value[$n+1])){

        $n++;
    }

    return $n+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use loops but may face the O(n) issue if strrpos uses strlen internally.

```
function length($str)
{
    return strrpos($str.'_', '_', -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_strlen($str)
{
    for($i=-1; isset($str[++$i]); );
    return $i;
}

echo my_strlen("q");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Hello World";
$count= 0;
while( isset($str[$count]) && $str[$count] ) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

OUTPUT: 
**11**

Answer (score 0):

Renverser un charactère sans Function

```
class StringFunction {

    public function strCount($string) {
        $cpt=0;
        //isset pour cacher l'erreur
        // Notice: Uninitialized string offset
        while(isset($string[$cpt])) {
            $cpt++;
        }

        return $cpt;
    }

    public function reverseChar($str) {

        //mes indexes
        $start = 0;
        $end = $this->strCount($str)-1;     

        //Si $start est inférieur à $end
        while ($start < $end) {
            //change position du charactère
            $temp = $str[$start];
            $str[$start] = $str[$end];
            $str[$end]   = $temp;

            $start++;
            $end--;
        }

        return $str;
    }
}

$string = "Bonjour";
$a = new StringFunction();

echo $string . "<br>";
echo $a->reverseChar($string);
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you when you don't want to use any inbuilt function of php.
You can test this here also
http://phptester.net/

```
<?php
$stings="Hello how are you?";
$ctr=0;
while(1){
    if(empty($stings[$ctr])){       
                break;
    }

    $ctr++;
}
echo $ctr;
```

Comment: isn't empty a build in function for php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str  = "aabccdab";
$i = 0;
$temp = array();
    while(isset($str[$i])){
        echo $str[$i];
        $count = 0;
        if(isset($temp[$str[$i]])){
            $temp[$str[$i]] = $temp[$str[$i]]+1;
        }else{
            $temp[$str[$i]] = 1;
        }
        $i++;
}
print_r($temp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "hello world";
$i = 0;
while ($str[$i] >= 0) {
    $i++;
}
echo "string length is: $i";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's going to be a heavy work for your server, but a way to handle it.

```
function($string){
  $c=0;
  while(true){
    if(!empty($string[$c])){
      $c=$c+1;
    } else {
      break; // Prevent errors with return.
    }
  }
  return $c;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "STRING";
$i=0; $count = 0;
while((isset($str{$i}) && $str{$i} != "")){
$i++; $count++;
}
print $count;
```

Comment: Instead of writing `while((isset($str{$i}) && $str{$i} != "")){
$i++; $count++;
}` you can write `while($str{$i} != ""){
$i++; $count++; if(!isset($str{$i})) break; 
}` to make function more readable.

Answer (score -1):

This can also help -

```
$s = 'string';
$temp = str_split($s); // Convert a string to an array by each character

// if don't want the spaces
$temp = array_filter($temp); // remove empty values

echo count($temp); // count the number of element in array
```

**Output**

```
6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$arr = array('vadapalanai','annanager','chennei','salem','coimbatore');

$min = $arr[0];

$max = $arr[0];

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    if (strlen($min) > strlen($val)) {
        $min = $val ;
    }
    if(strlen($max) < strlen($val)){
        $max = $val;
    }
}   
echo "The shortest array length is : " .$min. " ".strlen($min);
echo "<br>";
echo "The longest array length is: " .$max. " ".strlen($max);

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str  = 'I am XYZ'  
$count = 0;
$i=0;
while (isset($str[$i])) {  
 $count = $i;
 $i++; 
}  
echo $count;
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32567302)