# How to find string length in php without using strlen()

Tags: php, c

How to find string length in php without using `strlen()`?the condition is to take value of a=b=c=2, for words containing these alphabets?

Comment: Let me ask you whats wrong with `strlen()`.?If there is a built in function then why are you complicating the programming.?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989221/how-to-find-string-length-in-php-with-out-using-strlen

Comment: How will you not be thirsty without drinking liquids??

Comment: I know its very easy by using strlen but i cant use it ,Because its my task .

Comment: so no answer was correct for you???

Comment: @Legionar: all answers were correct but i mentioned that i have to put condition on it... see my answer according to my requirement

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an interviewer questioned you... Well you can use **`mb_strlen()`**

```
<?php
echo mb_strlen("Hello World");
```

(or)

Use this.. read it somewhere before on SO

```
<?php
echo array_sum(count_chars("Hello World"));
```

Answer (score 1):

it might help you... not tested...

```
   $s = 'string';
   $i=0;
    while ($s[$i] != '') {
      $i++;
    }
    print $i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mb_strlen()`, it will process Unicode strings.

Or use this function:

```
function get_string_length($string) {
  $i = 0;

  while ($string{$i} != '') {
    $i++;
  }

  return $i;
}
```

echo get_string_length('aaaaa'); // will echo 5

Comment: put @ in while (@$string{$i} != '') then correct output.

Comment: No, thats wrong. I added there `&`

Comment: this1 needs  @ ,infact i am not getting satisfactory answer that why put@ this

Comment: That function is working, and there is no reason to have there `@`

Comment: may be but really not working on my system...

Comment: I am sure, that this `get_string_length('aaaaa');` will return `5`. Test once again that function.

Comment: i checked it ... u r right , happy

Comment: all answers were correct but i mentioned that i have to put condition on it... see my answer according to my requiremen

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). strlen() is broken for Unicode strings, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function mystrlen($str) {
     $count = 0;
     for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        if (@$str[$i] != "") {
            if (@$str[$i] == "a" || @$str[$i] == "b" || @$str[$i] == "c") {
                $count+=2;
            } else {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

echo mystrlen("this is temporary but we made it complex");
?>
```

Comment: And what if string length is > 1000000??

Comment: this is not difficult, u can remove and extend this r infinte , if u want.. i took this as an example

Comment: how will you write infinite in `for` loop??

Comment: you can use while lopp for infinite purpose or put nothing in for loop for infinte looping

Comment: ??? in my answer there is `while` loop... So then my answer is correct for you...

Comment: yeah thats true but i was only asking about this @ symbol, bcz ur code was not giving output without this1.. otherwise u wrote right code, as well as right while loop :P